# jQuery append merging divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

I've got this simple HTML element:

```
<div class="progress hidden-tmp" id="progress-template">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

I then proceed to load this as jQuery element:

```
const TEMPLATE = '#progress-template';

constructor(name, parent) {
    this.name = name;

    /** @type {jQuery|Element} */
    this.element = $(TEMPLATE).clone().attr('id', 'progress-' + name);
    this.moveTo(parent);
}
```

Later I append this element to "parent", which is another jQuery element #example:

```
/**
 * Puts progressbar to parent element and set it visible
 * @param {jQuery|Element} parent
 */
moveTo(parent) {
    this.element.detach();
    console.log(this.element.prop('outerHTML'));
    parent.append(this.element);
    this.element.show();
}
```

If I run the above, the console.log shows this (which is correct):

```
<div class="progress hidden-tmp" id="progress-myBar">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

But this is what is appended to parent div:

```
<div class="progress hidden-tmp progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-myBar" style="display: block; width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```

It appears that both divs in element got merged into one. Any ideas why?

Comment: Btw, jQuery is version 2.2.4 because of Bootstrap 3.3.7. Later versions of jQuery breaks the BS Affix functionality.

Comment: The last example has a `style` attribute that has not been present before. Logical conclusion: There is some other code that manipulates the HTML.

Comment: @zeroflagL Ah, thanks for pointing that out. My coworker added code that changes inner HTML. That solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I've forgot there is one line that was also playing with inner HTML of that element. So append() works perfectly fine.